# Where can I find the norms for Raven's Standard Progressive Matrices?

Tags: intelligence, statistics, test, iq

I've never had my IQ measured before. After some research I decided to take the Raven's Standard Progressive Matrix test. After Googling I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven%27s_Progressive_Matrices) Wikipedia page. [This test](http://www.free-iq-test.org/) was linked on the Wikipedia page, and I took the test and acquired my raw score.

I understand that I may need to take the advanced version of the test if my score is high enough, but that's besides the point. After acquiring my raw score, I researched how to get a rough IQ conversion. I found [this question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4483/how-to-calculate-iq-score-based-on-raw-score-and-adjust-for-age) here. It describes how to convert your raw score to a z-score, and then get a rough estimate of IQ from the z-score.

However, acquiring the z-score requires norms for the raw scores, if I'm not mistaken.

Where can I find the norms? Specifically, I need the mean raw score and the standard deviation for the United States general population.

Comment: Also: [How to obtain adult norms for Raven's progressive matrices?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16203/7001)